# jQuery trigger click not working from AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When I click submit on a form, it makes an AJAX call. If the return value is `success` I want to open a file upload browser to upload a file from the system. For this I am using the trigger click from jQuery on `success` message. But it is not working. Below is the code for the AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
  url: AppManager.defaults.contextPath,
  data: colMap,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.result == 'Success') {
      $('#continue-upload-input-box').trigger('click');
    } else {
      self.popupView.closePopup();
      notify.popup('Error Uploading').error(self.uploadFailureMessage);
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

This is where the code for file upload is written:

```
change: function($view) {
  var self = this;
  $('<form id="custom-upload" class="input-form-container" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>').appendTo($view.find('.btn-wrap'));
  $view.find('.input-form-container').after('<input name="excelFile" type="file" id="continue-upload-input-box" style="display:none;">');
  $view.find('#continue-upload-input-box').off('change').on('change', function(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length === 1) {
      self.uploadCustomTemplate(new FormData($('#custom-upload')[0]));
      self.popupView.closePopup();
    }
  });
}
```

What could be an issue in the above code?

Comment: You are not appending the response into `DOM`, Are you?? Unless you have it in `DOM`, you cannot have any `events` for it.

Comment: I don't see your `click` event callback for your element. Have you bound one?

Answer (score 2):

you need to action a dom click event, not a jQuery click event.

try:-

```
$('#continue-upload-input-box').get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(document).trigger
```

insted of

```
$('#continue-upload-input-box').trigger('click');
```

if you use document then it will execute your trigger event . if your id is not in DOM when you trigger click it will not execute so you have to load DOM again

Answer (score 0):

Use on method for calling event.refer following link:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

first make sure your 'data.result' value 'Success' is in correct format or which value it will return then use this

$("#continue-upload-input-box").trigger("click");

i think your code is proper but it's all depends on your other jquery code

Answer (score 0):

.trigger is more or less like a click.
to trigger some action/event the element or object must be in DOM before your trigger the event.
So if you load the form from JS and then append it in DOM the your function that allow the uploader to show must be in .load function OR its better that you append it in DOM before the ajax fires.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score -1):

Use `$('#continue-upload-input-box').click();`. That should be sufficient.

Comment: `.click()` with no parameters is a shorthand for `.trigger("click")`